# Regex Extract ID From URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have url like this `domain.com/news-343dds-this-is-test`

I want to extract news id `343dds`,
so I tried to use regex

Here is the regex I used `/news-(.+)-/`

But the result is like this `343dds-this-is`. I only want get the `343dds`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(.+)` is being greedy and matching the rest of the input. Change it to `(.+?)` to make it not greedy.

Answer (score 2):

Jeremy Hanlon's solution obviously works but is not the most recommended one.

You had better using `([^-]+)`.

Even if it probably doesn't matter in simple cases such as this SO question, the lazy quantifier `+?` has the inconvenient that the number of steps is proportional to the size of the searched part, so it may widely impact performance.
This is clearly explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Example:

- `(.+?)` [needs 22 steps](https://regex101.com/r/bS9wG9/1) for the given `343dds` key
- `(.+?)` [needs 68 steps](https://regex101.com/r/kZ5aM9/1) for a longer key like `thisIsASignificativelyLongKey`
- `([^-]+)` [needs 12 steps](https://regex101.com/r/eN9sY9/1) only for any key

Comment: Ya this is a nice answer. But how the steps are calculated.?

Comment: @mkHun The long answer is given by the "here" link above. The short one is (with `(.+?)`): 1) the engine founds that the 1st char after "news-" matches `.+` but the 2nd one doesn't match `-` (this is one step); 2) then it goes back, founds that the 1st and 2nd chars match `.+` but the 3d one doesn't match `-` (this is one step); 3) then it goes back... and so on till founding 1st to nth chars match `.+` AND n+1th matches `-`. So it needs as many steps as the size of the searched string part!